# Is it safe to use a non-overclockable CPU on an overclocker motherboard?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, overclocking

I am running an **Intel Core i5-4670** (**without** the K for the overclocker edition) processor on a **Z78 - PLUS** motherboard from ASUS.

Initially the [ASUS AI suite was overclocking my processor](https://superuser.com/questions/676833/core-i5-processor-running-too-fast). Now that I have reverted the BIOS settings to the **default settings**, am I safe? It was rather shocking to see that it's to easy to apply the wrong settings.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?  **The motherboard was design to work with ALL Haswell parts.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run a normal processor on a board designed for overclocking.
while you cannot adjust the multi, you could still adjust things like strap and Bclk, to overclock anyway.

If you want to make sure it is all running normal, then it still helps to know some of the things that take it off normal.  To check with CPU-Z or other tools to verify that it is normal.

You could disable the service items and/or drivers for the asus aisuite , that would stop it from having any control, until you get things sorted out.

Learning all that stuff was not done in a day for anyone, you'll get it,  find a Guide, and follow it, with mabey lower settings.

Comment: Thanks, I am learning a lot already :) Yes, I have disabled the drivers for now.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, overclocking can be achieved by either modifying the front side bus (FSB) speed or the multiplier.

The K only means there's an unlocked multiplier, so even for the regular Intel CPUs, you can overclock by pushing the FSB speed.  Increase the bus speed allows for some overclocking, but it's less than changing the multiplier would allow for.

In any case, it sounds like you accidentally applied the automatic tuning that your motherboard allows, which slightly overclocked your CPU.

As for are you safe, most modern CPUs are pretty intelligent about clocking down or shutting down if they cross thermal thresholds or what not.  The Asus tools are likely pretty decent at knowing/detecting what an acceptable limit to push your particular CPU is.  If the system was stable, you probably didn't damage the CPU . . . you may have decreased it's lifespan somewhat, but there's no real way of knowing.  As long as you're not constantly running the CPU at full speed (meaning the highest heat), and have decent cooling, the risk of damaging a CPU is low, even when overclocking via bumping the FSB.